# Calling a servlet from a jsp and return back a jsp

Tags: java

I tried to access a servlet from a jsp and then the code with the webservice if the array list passes as 0. It should show a image and if it passes 1 it should show a different jsp. I am able to generate the code but it is not working as expected. Can any one figure out what the problem is.

package sal;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Amberalerts
 */
public class Amberalerts extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        List  list = getList();
        if(list != null && list.size() != 0){
          dispatchToShowJsp(req, resp, "/ShowImage.jsp");
        }else{
            dispatchToShowJsp(req, resp, "/ShowDefaultMsg.jsp");
        }

        // writeImageTOBuffer(resp);
    }
    private List getList() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Result");
        return list;
    }
    private void dispatchToShowJsp(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp, String jsplocation) throws IOException {
        try {
            getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    jsplocation).forward(req,resp);
        } catch (ServletException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */


    private void writeImageTOBuffer(HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // Get the absolute path of the image
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        String filename = sc.getRealPath("rsc/image.gif");

        // Get the MIME type of the image
        String mimeType = sc.getMimeType(filename);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            sc.log("Could not get MIME type of "+filename);
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }

        // Set content type
        resp.setContentType(mimeType);

        // Set content size
        File file = new File(filename);
        resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        // Open the file and output streams
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain "not working" in detail. The code just does what it is told to do. What happens instead?

Comment: I am trying to access the image from the servletcontext but it is calling the "/ShowImage.jsp" where i have hardcoded the image as src="c:/image.jpeg";But i want my image to be rendered from the servlet context.Is there any code changes i need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Of note, your code won't work because your call to `writeImageToBuffer` is commented out, and your if/else statement in `doGet(req,resp)` will always call the `dispatchToShowJsp()` method.

Regardless, using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to help some of the busywork, you can call the `sendImageToResponse` method below to send your image out:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ShowImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

        public void sendImageToResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        File imageFile = new File("PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE_FILE"); // configure this however you want

        OutputStream outStream = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;

        try {

            outStream = response.getOutputStream();

            // Open image file
            inStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(imageFile);

            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

            System.out.println("SENDING " + imageFile);

            // Send image file
            IOUtils.copy(inStream, outStream);

            System.out.println("SENT SIZE=" + imageFile.length());

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // Handle your exception

        } finally {

            // close image file
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inStream);

            try {

                // flush stream
                outStream.flush();

            } catch (Exception ignore) {

                // Ignore

            } finally {

                IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```